# Linq Stored Procedure Issue- Returning an int

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, int

I am trying to call a stored procedure with Linq, the stored procedure returns the value fine in SQL, but when I drag it onto my DBML file and try and call it from my code it is returning the

> *Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'.  'Select' not found.*

I've looked at other threads and other stored procedures I have and for some reason rather than  using an `ISingleResult` this is different and I cant seem to change the Return Type either.

This is the DBML code behind

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.displayDetails")]
public int displayDetails([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="VarChar(1)")] string sex, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> day, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> month, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> year, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="PostCode", DbType="VarChar(10)")] string postCode, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="AppTime", DbType="DateTime")] System.Nullable<System.DateTime> appTime, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> filter)
{
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), sex, day, month, year, postCode, appTime, filter);
        return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

My page code which is getting the error

```
    var person = from p in db.displayDetails(sex.ToString(),
                  Convert.ToInt32(dayOfBirth),
                  Convert.ToInt32(monthOfBirth),
                  Convert.ToInt32(yearOfBirth),
                  postCode.ToString(),
                  Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentTime),
                  Convert.ToInt32(resultType))
                  select person;
        {
            p.Forename,
            p.Surname,
            p.AppointmentTime,
            p.Location
        };

        foreach (var record in person)
        {
            lblName.Text = record.Forename + " " + record.Surname;
            lblAppointmentTime.Text = record.AppointmentTime.ToString();
            lblWaitIn.Text = record.Location;
        }
```

Any help on how to get this resolved would be appreciated.

Update - Hi, here is my SP:

```
@sex varchar (1),
@day int,
@month int,
@year int,
@PostCode varchar (10),
@AppTime DateTime,
@filter int

AS
BEGIN

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

Select @Sql = 'SELECT DAY(DateOfBirth) AS DayOfBirth, MONTH(DateOfBirth) AS MonthOfBirth, 
YEAR(DateOfBirth) AS YearOfBirth, DateOfBirth, Sex, AppointmentTime, SchdlRefno, Forename, 
Surname, ClinicCode, Ur, PostCode, Specialty, Location
FROM dbo.tbl_Appointments'


if @filter  = 1
-- show search by just sex, day and month as no more needed for match
Select @sql = @Sql + ' WHERE (DAY(DateOfBirth) = ' + convert(varchar, @day, 103) + ') AND (MONTH(DateOfBirth) = ' + convert(varchar, @month, 103) + ') AND (Sex = ''' + @sex + ''')' 

if @filter  = 2

-- show search by sex, day and month and postcode

Select @sql = @Sql + ' WHERE (DAY(DateOfBirth) = ' + convert(varchar, @day, 103) + ') AND (MONTH(DateOfBirth) = ' + convert(varchar, @month, 103) + ') and (YEAR(DateOfBirth) = ' + convert(varchar, @year, 103) + ') AND (Sex = ''' + @sex + ''') and (postcode = ''' + @postcode + ''')' 

if @filter  = 3

-- show search by sex, day and month, postcode and appointment time

Select @sql = @Sql + ' WHERE (DAY(DateOfBirth) = ' + convert(varchar, @day, 103) + ') AND (MONTH(DateOfBirth) = ' + convert(varchar, @month, 103) + ') and (YEAR(DateOfBirth) = ' + convert(varchar, @year, 103) + ') AND (Sex = ''' + @sex + ''') and (postcode = ''' + @postcode + ''') and (AppointmentTime = ''' + convert(varchar, @AppTime, 121) + ''')' 

print @sql  

Exec sp_executesql  @sql

END
```

So, im passing a filter through to bring back different search results.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the result of your function isn't a collection, it's a scalar value (`int`) therefore can't be projected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But how do I go about changing this as its not something i've come across before?

Comment: @Adamsk1 you need to update your SP to return the actual query results instead of an integer value. Could you post the implementation details of your SP?

Comment: @Adamsk1 I would update your question to show the implementation of your SP.

Comment: Looks like your using dynamic SQL - make sure your clued up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your query looks ok (assume this returns values ok in the designer?). I think with dynamic SQL the L2S generator struggles to find the return type so you could try dumping the results of your query to a temp table and having your SP do a `SELECT` from that after you execute the SQL.

Comment: Everything comes back fine when I run in in SQL management studio and the sql it prints out is all good to. I will have a look at the option of a temporary table unless you recommend any other method of doing what I am trying to do? Thanks

Comment: I think a temp table & re-generating your Stored Proc on the DBML should work. The only other way I can think of is modifying the DBML XML to force the return type...I reckon the temp table way is more reliable though.

Comment: This has done the trick with the temp table route. Thanks again for your help! :-)