# Avoid extra loop and could not find implementation of query pattern for source type int Select not found

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

How I can avoid Extra loop and construct order in the LINQ quest itself.

```
GetOrderListDataContext orderListDaCtx = new GetOrderListDataContext(address);
// This line showing compiler error could not find implementation of query pattern for source type int Select not found
var orderList = from order in orderListDaCtx.Base_Purchase_GetOrderListByUser_WS(request.UserGuid, request.CountryCode, request.FromDate, request.ToDate)
                select order;
// Here how i can avoid this loop and construct order object in the LINQ itself above                   
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
foreach (var order in orderList)
{
    orders.Add(new Order
     {
         OrderKey = order.OrderKey,
         UserEmail = order.UserEmail,
         CreatedDate = order.CreatedDate
     });
}
return orders;
```

Comment: You use 3 fields from the DB result, but how many are there in the actual model? If it is more than 3, is the `Order` class you are using the same as the DB entity or different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do You mean this?

```
GetOrderListDataContext orderListDaCtx = new GetOrderListDataContext(address);
var orderList = from order in orderListDaCtx.Base_Purchase_GetOrderListByUser_WS(request.UserGuid, request.CountryCode, request.FromDate, request.ToDate)
select new Order{
         OrderKey = order.OrderKey,
         UserEmail = order.UserEmail,
         CreatedDate = order.CreatedDate
}

return orderList.ToList();
```

Comment: could not find implementation of query pattern for source type int Select not found

Comment: need to using System.Linq;

Comment: +1 again before the OP use this. he must fix the first problem

Answer (score 1):

You can just chain:

```
var orders = orderListDaCtx.Base_Purchase_GetOrderListByUser_WS(request.UserGuid, request.CountryCode, request.FromDate, request.ToDate)
                           .Select(order => new Order
                             {
                               OrderKey = order.OrderKey,
                               UserEmail = order.UserEmail,
                               CreatedDate = order.CreatedDate
                             })
                           .ToList();
return orders;
```

Comment: Your query shows complier error "could not find implementation of query pattern for source type int Select not found"

Comment: +1 this correct.. but before the OP use this. he must fix the first problem

Answer (score 1):

> This line showing compiler error could not find implementation of
>   query pattern for source type int Select not found

You main problem is from your stored procedure. Refer: [Linq Stored Procedure Issue- Returning an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682812/linq-stored-procedure-issue-returning-an-int)

Answer (score 0):

See [LINQ Error](http://joshrharrison.com/archive/2008/12/16/linq-error-could-not-find-an-implementation-of-the-query.aspx):

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Your.Type'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable

It's likely that `orderListDaCtx.Base_Purchase_GetOrderListByUser_WS(request.UserGuid, request.CountryCode, request.FromDate, request.ToDate)` returns type 'IEnumerable', but the `LINQ` requires `IEnumerable<T>`. You have to perform explicit cast:

```
var orderList = from Order order in orderListDaCtx.Base_Purchase_GetOrderListByUser_WS(request.UserGuid, request.CountryCode, request.FromDate, request.ToDate)
                select order;
```

I assume, that that `Base_Purchase_GetOrderListByUser_WS` returns collection of `Order`.